# Bat to run a compiled .exe with color green

Tags: batch-file

is there any way to set the color of a simple compiled executable?I am not trying to touch the source code of the executable.What I got so far is:

```
COLOR fc
start sqwer.exe
```

However,it's not working.Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `start` you'll start a new CMD with the standard color.

try running the exe like this :

```
COLOR fc
sqwer.exe
```